# Unable to use factory girl with Cucumber and rails 3 (bundler problem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot, bundler

I'm trying to run cucumber features with factory girl factories on a fresh Rails 3 application.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source "http://gemcutter.org"
gem "rails", "3.0.0.beta"
gem "pg"
gem "factory_girl", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl.git", :branch => "rails3"
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0.beta.4"
gem "capybara"
gem "database_cleaner"
gem "cucumber-rails", :require => false
```

Then the bundle install commande just runs smoothly:

```
$ bundle install
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:81:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
Updating git://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl.git
Fetching source index from http://gemcutter.org
Resolving dependencies
Installing abstract (1.0.0) from system gems 
Installing actionmailer (3.0.0.beta) from system gems 
Installing actionpack (3.0.0.beta) from system gems 
Installing activemodel (3.0.0.beta) from system gems 
Installing activerecord (3.0.0.beta) from system gems 
Installing activeresource (3.0.0.beta) from system gems 
Installing activesupport (3.0.0.beta) from system gems 
Installing arel (0.2.1) from system gems 
Installing builder (2.1.2) from system gems 
Installing bundler (0.9.13) from system gems 
Installing capybara (0.3.6) from system gems 
Installing cucumber (0.6.3) from system gems 
Installing cucumber-rails (0.3.0) from system gems 
Installing culerity (0.2.9) from system gems 
Installing database_cleaner (0.5.0) from system gems 
Installing diff-lcs (1.1.2) from system gems 
Installing erubis (2.6.5) from system gems 
Installing factory_girl (1.2.3) from git://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl.git (at rails3) 
Installing ffi (0.6.3) from system gems 
Installing i18n (0.3.6) from system gems 
Installing json_pure (1.2.3) from system gems 
Installing mail (2.1.3) from system gems 
Installing memcache-client (1.7.8) from system gems 
Installing mime-types (1.16) from system gems 
Installing nokogiri (1.4.1) from system gems 
Installing pg (0.9.0) from system gems 
Installing polyglot (0.3.0) from system gems 
Installing rack (1.1.0) from system gems 
Installing rack-mount (0.4.7) from system gems 
Installing rack-test (0.5.3) from system gems 
Installing rails (3.0.0.beta) from system gems 
Installing railties (3.0.0.beta) from system gems 
Installing rake (0.8.7) from system gems 
Installing rspec (2.0.0.beta.4) from system gems 
Installing rspec-core (2.0.0.beta.4) from system gems 
Installing rspec-expectations (2.0.0.beta.4) from system gems 
Installing rspec-mocks (2.0.0.beta.4) from system gems 
Installing rspec-rails (2.0.0.beta.4) from system gems 
Installing selenium-webdriver (0.0.17) from system gems 
Installing term-ansicolor (1.0.5) from system gems 
Installing text-format (1.0.0) from system gems 
Installing text-hyphen (1.0.0) from system gems 
Installing thor (0.13.4) from system gems 
Installing treetop (1.4.4) from system gems 
Installing tzinfo (0.3.17) from system gems 
Installing webrat (0.7.0) from system gems 
Your bundle is complete!
```

When I run cucumber, here is the error I get:

```
$ rake cucumber
(in /home/jbpros/projects/deorbitburn)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:97:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "posts_id_seq" for serial column "posts.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "posts_pkey" for table "posts"
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -I "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/lib:lib" "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/cucumber"  --profile default
Using the default profile...
git://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl.git (at rails3) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::PathError)
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/source.rb:282:in `load_spec_files'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/source.rb:190:in `local_specs'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/environment.rb:36:in `runtime_gems'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/environment.rb:35:in `each'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/environment.rb:35:in `runtime_gems'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/index.rb:5:in `build'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/environment.rb:34:in `runtime_gems'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/environment.rb:14:in `index'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/index.rb:5:in `build'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/environment.rb:13:in `index'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/environment.rb:55:in `resolve_locally'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/environment.rb:28:in `specs'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/environment.rb:65:in `specs_for'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
/home/jbpros/.bundle/gems/bundler-0.9.13/lib/bundler.rb:68:in `setup'
/home/jbpros/projects/deorbitburn/config/boot.rb:7
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `polyglot_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.0/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/jbpros/projects/deorbitburn/config/application.rb:1
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `polyglot_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.0/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/jbpros/projects/deorbitburn/config/environment.rb:2
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `polyglot_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.0/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/jbpros/projects/deorbitburn/features/support/env.rb:8
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `polyglot_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.0/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:124:in `load_code_file'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:85:in `load_code_file'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:77:in `load_code_files'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:76:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:76:in `load_code_files'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:48:in `execute!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/cucumber:8
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -I "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1....]

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Do I have to do something special for bundler to check out factory girl's repository on github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. I was running bundler 0.9.3. Upgrading to 0.9.13 and running 'bundle install` fixed everything.

Answer (score 3):

on a side note you may want to include 'factory_girl_rails' instead of factory_girl in your gemfile

as this is a fix for rails 3
we found that although our factories worked with cucumber they didnt work with test:unit until we had this gem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run `bundle pack` ?

Comment: I did and it does not work neither. What's weird is that bundle pack does not seem to copy factory girl to vendor/: http://pastie.org/889955